# writegood mode in code

Tags: comment, style

I like to use writegood-mode for my source code comments. I feel that there should be a way to make it check comments only. However, my python files display that kind of things:

[image]

and so does bash mode:

[image]

How can I setup writegood-mode to check only comments, or what are alternatives for style checking my comments?

Comment: I assume you've read the package's website documentation.  Another option is to see what functions or variables the writegood package exposes to users. Type `C-h f` for functions and `C-h v` for variables.  Write the namespace prefix, `writegood`, and press `<TAB>`.  This will bring up all the exposed options.  If there's one which seems promising, read the internal documentation on it.  If nothing looks good, then your next step would be to look at the source code.  There's a link to that in every `writegood` doc page.  Maybe the author has internal functions you could use.

Comment: @Lorem Ipsum I've done that, but couldn't find anything that seemed relevant. Not saying there's nothing to be found, but I did make an effort. I can't find anything related to "code mode" or "comments only" in variable names, functions names, or writegood-mode.el.

Comment: There's `writegood-duplicates-turn-off`, which is what erroneously highlight in my screenshots above, but it would be nice to leave on for comments.